# i wanna print in excel file using c++ in some way

Tags: c++, excel, file, c++14

I have 2 arrays and I wanna to write them into excel sheet so I wrote this code to write into sheet excel

```
ofstream file ("out.csv",ios::out|ios::app);
file<<s[1]<<w[1]<<endl;
file<<s[2]<<w[2]<<endl;
file.close();
```

When I opened the file, I found it like this:

```
s1w1|
----------
s2w2|
----------
```

But I want every element to be in a cell like below:

```
----------
s1|w1|
----------
s2|w2|
```

Comment: C++ doesn't know about the CSV format, you have to stream the , or ; yourselves

Comment: `file<<s[1]<<','<<w[1]<<endl;
file<<s[2]<<','<<w[2]<<endl;`